# EF 4.1 Bidirectional one-to-one problem

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

Hi I am having a problem with a simple EF 4.1 code first model.

I have a class person and a class survey that are bidirectionally linked. The database model is correct but I always get this error:

```
Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'DAL.Models.Survey' and 'DAL.Models.Person'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.
```

Class Person

```
[Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public virtual Survey Survey { get; set; }
```

Class Survey

```
   [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public bool IsFinished { get; set; }

        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
```

Datacontext:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Survey>().HasRequired(s => s.Person).WithOptional().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Can anyone help please

Answer (score 1):

You should define the other navigation property in your mapping since you have it in the model. Otherwise EF will create a second (one-to-many) association:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Survey>()
            .HasRequired(s => s.Person)
            .WithOptional(p => p.Survey)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Comment: @Nealv: Hm, strange. I have copied your model and mapping exactly into a test project and I don't get an error (even not with your original mapping code). It's also described here as valid mapping: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/04/14/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations.aspx Do you have any other Fluent mapping on `Survey` or `Person` class? Do you create the database from your model or are you working with an existing DB? (I'm going to remove the CTP5 remark from my answer.)

Comment: @Nealv: Could you check that the code with your Fluent Mapping is really executed (by setting a breakpoint or so)? I've just seen that I also get this error when I don't have this fluent mapping (which makes sense because principal and dependent cannot be determined from the model classes alone).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to specify either a foreign key property through HasForeignKey or foreign key column name using Map. Something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Survey>()
    .HasRequired(s => s.Person)
    .WithOptional()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true)
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("fk_column"));
```